# loss precision when using numpy savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

When I tried to use numpy savetxt to save results to file, I run into loss of precision

```
for i in range(24):
     # starting from [30,40] increasing slope per time slot
     line[2*i] = 30+i*slope
     print("line{0} = {1}".format(2*i, 30+i*slope))
     line[2*i+1] = 40+i*slope
     print("line{0} = {1}".format(2*i+1, 40+i*slope))
np.savetxt(f, [line], delimiter=',', fmt ='%f')
```

Here the slope is 0.5, say.
The print result is exactly what I expected.

```
line0 = 30.0
line1 = 40.0
line2 = 30.5
line3 = 40.5
...
```

However, when I open the save txt file, what I get is,

```
30.000000,40.000000,30.000000,40.000000,31.000000,41.000000
```

My question is why 30.5 becomes 30 in the third element? I suppose there is no default int conversion?

Comment: @HenryEcker, I also thought so, but the documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language): "With no precision given, [`%f`] uses a precision of 6 digits after the decimal point for `float`", and we do indeed see 6 digits, but they're all zeros...

Comment: I found out the issue, the way I initialize line was not correct. Instead of ```np.array([0 for i in range(48)])```, I should have used ```np.array([0.0 for i in range(48)])```. '%f' seems correct now. A float with 0 decimal places? We should check on that, because now it gives me the correct answer ```30.000000,40.000000,30.500000,40.500000,```

Comment: Yeah. I was wrong, the problem is that `line` is a np.array of type `int`. Run `line = line.astype(float)` before the loop and try it.

Comment: What's the type of elements in `line`? What's `line.dtype`? Is it `int`, by any chance?

Comment: @XuSiyuan, you could also use `np.zeros(48)`

Comment: Thank you!! @ForceBru@Henry Ecker